# Geotools vector grid not showing

Tags: geotools

I am working on a Maps Application using geotools, but since recently my grid layer stopped showing for no reason !

There is a WMS map representing the earth, and a FeatureLayer representing a grid with 10° squares (Geographic WGS84).

Here is my code to initialize my mapcontent. For the grid, I tried to set a grid on Australia like the vector grid geotools tutorial

```java
public void initMap(int w, int h)
{
  mapContent = new MapContent();
  mapContent.getViewport().setMatchingAspectRatio(true);
  mapContent.getViewport().setFixedBoundsOnResize(false);
 
  // WMS
  wmsLayer = new WMSLayer(wmsConnection, selectedLayer);
  
  ReferencedEnvelope dataBounds = wmsLayer.getBounds();
  CoordinateReferenceSystem dataCrs = dataBounds.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();

  mapContent.addLayer(wmsLayer);

  mapContent.getViewport().setScreenArea(new Rectangle(w, h));
  mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(dataBounds);
  mapContent.getViewport().setCoordinateReferenceSystem(dataCrs);

  // Grid
  ReferencedEnvelope gridBounds = new ReferencedEnvelope(110, 150, -45, -8, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);

  FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> lonLatGrid = Grids.createSquareGrid(gridBounds, 10);
  ReprojectingFeatureCollection rfc;

  try {
    SimpleFeatureCollection sfc = (SimpleFeatureCollection)lonLatGrid.getFeatures();
    rfc = new ReprojectingFeatureCollection(sfc, mapContent.getViewport().getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
  } catch (IOException e)
  {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }

  Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(rfc.getSchema());

  FeatureLayer grid = new FeatureLayer(rfc, style);
  mapContent.addLayer(grid);
}
```

I am then rendering the map on a JavaFX Canvas with StreamingRenderer. WMS Layer is rendered properly, but the FeatureLayer isn't showing at all :c.

Here is the log corresponding to geotools (the Enveloppe now corresponds to the whole earth and not just Australia) :

```
2023-02-16 14:50:26.739 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Computed scale denominator: 7.687380703318137E7
2023-02-16 14:50:26.740 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : creating rules for scale denominator - 76,873,807.033
2023-02-16 14:50:26.740 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.styling                     : creating defaultMark
2023-02-16 14:50:26.741 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.styling                     : creating defaultMark
2023-02-16 14:50:26.741 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.data.util                   : CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2023-02-16 14:50:26.741 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.data.util                   : InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2023-02-16 14:50:26.741 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.data.util                   : CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2023-02-16 14:50:26.741 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.data.util                   : InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2023-02-16 14:50:26.741 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.data.util                   : CRSConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to CRS  only.
2023-02-16 14:50:26.741 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.data.util                   : InterpolationConverterFactory can be applied from Strings to Interpolation only.
2023-02-16 14:50:26.741 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Processing 1 stylers for http://www.opengis.net/gml:grid
2023-02-16 14:50:26.741 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Expanding rendering area by 2 pixels to consider stroke width
2023-02-16 14:50:26.742 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Querying layer http://www.opengis.net/gml:grid with bbox: ReferencedEnvelope[-139.28905476171872 : 108.9843689453125, -60.03515721679681 : 107.02733350195317]
2023-02-16 14:50:26.743 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.styling                     : creating defaultMark
2023-02-16 14:50:26.765 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.renderer.label              : TOTAL LINE LABELS : 0
2023-02-16 14:50:26.765 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.renderer.label              : PAINTED LINE LABELS : 0
2023-02-16 14:50:26.765 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.renderer.label              : REMAINING LINE LABELS : 0
2023-02-16 14:50:26.765 DEBUG 133118 --- [lication Thread] org.geotools.renderer.lite               : Style cache hit ratio: 0.9977777777777778 , hits 449, requests 450
```

Thank you for your time !

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Done ! Sorry if I put too many/too few information, I struggle to figure out what is relevant

Comment: @IanTurton Do you have any idea of how I should interpret those logs ? I have no clue of where is the problem

Comment: You need to find the log that relates to drawing your grid (which I don't think is in the part you posted). I would also attach a debugger and check if your CRS is correct and that your bounding box has the correct axis order for the CRS.

Comment: @IanTurton I just cropped the logs so it only shows the part of the Grid drawing. I'll try to verify my CRS but I think the only projections I use are default WGS84.

Comment: `ReferencedEnvelope(110, 150, -45, -8,` looks like you are using lon/lat while I would expect most of GeoTools to be expecting lat/lon - but that can depend on other settings you may have used

Comment: @IanTurton the problem is still there when I initialize gridBounds with dataBounds, (that I reproject to DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84) knowing that I'm sure that dataBounds are valid (I can request a WMS Map from those bounds)

Comment: in the logs your request is for eferencedEnvelope[-139.28905476171872 : 108.9843689453125, -60.03515721679681 : 107.02733350195317] which does overlap but is quite different

Comment: @IanTurton I've done some Panning/Zooming before taking the logs. Sorry I didn't mention !